# What is the distribution of $Y_t = {W_t | W_T = x}$, constructed from Wiener process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

> $W_t$ is a Wiener process, $W_0 = 0$. Let $Y_t \,\,\text{be}\,\, {W_t | W_T = x}$. What is the distribution of $Y_t$?

I am not so sure, I do get that $W_T - W_t = x - W_t$ would depend on $(T-t)$ and without the condition $W_t$ would have a normal distribution, but I have no idea how to work around this condition on $Y_t$ and how it would affect $Y_t$ distributions. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that $(W_t,W_T)$ is a bivariate Gaussian vector, so the conditional distributions of its components can be explicitly calculated as explained here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions